# Failed to load resource: CodeIgniter (works fine locally)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I've just transferred a project of mine to the web and I have a file called `"circlecrop.php"` that's located in the root directory of where all the CodeIgniter files are. This php script basicall just makes any image with `circlecrop.php?path=img` cropped to a circle, very simple and it works fine locally.

This works perfectly fine locally.

**I'm getting the following error:**

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

I can't access circlecrop.php directly even though I've got it set to 777, I haven't anything set within my routes in CodeIgniter I'm not sure it's needed?

**Complete htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|circlecrop\.php|images|js|profile_pictures|fonts|stylesheets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've done some searching and can't seem to find anything, my only thought is that I need a way to directly access `circlecrop.php` and it will work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Edit:** I've updated the url that has the errors, maybe that's more helpful.

Comment: Perhaps turn circlecrop.php into a CI helper or library?

Comment: I did try but it was far too complex for what it's worth, especially since I had it working instantly locally. Is there no way for me to say to CodeIgniter/htaccess to allow direct access to circlecrop.php?

Comment: You do realise that there is no such domain as **website_adress.com** ?

Comment: Yes... It was just an example as to what my address is.

Comment: Then show us the real link and errors.

Comment: What happens if you add `circlecrop\.php`to the first `RewriteCond`?

Comment: Hey share here your complete htaccess file

Comment: @RizwanSultan I've just updated it with the complete htaccess file.

Comment: @Xiy please make sure you added rewrite base in your htaccess file

Comment: @RizwanSultan Added like so, is that correct?

Comment: Your website hosted on root directory or any sub directory?

Comment: Could it be your webhost has disabled directory listings in the server? See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403 : "The Apache web server returns 403 Forbidden in response to requests for url paths that correspond to filesystem directories, when directory listings have been disabled in the server."

Comment: I'm not too sure @Mudshark as I have it working fine here: http://wpvault.com/image_test/ (same server). Rizwan Sultan It's hosted in crownedtraders.com (folder).

Answer (score 1):

You need to include if your website placed on root directory

```
RewriteBase /
```

If it place in test folder for example use this.

```
RewriteBase /test/
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `site_url()` on every link and action instead of `base_url()`.

Comment: Indeed, although the main problem was the permissions issue with my host.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

I replace .htaccess content by the following:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|application/themes|application/theme_path|images|assets|robots.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Update your `base_url` according to your live host in `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'SET YOUR SITE URL HERE';
```

`config.php` is located in /application/config